# SQL Timestamp to Perl : How to add a day then?

Tags: sql, perl, date, timestamp

First, I get a `TIMESTAMP` in a SQL Format from a database in a Perl script, then I use `substr` to split the TIMESTAMP into five different parts (year, month, day, hour, minute and seconds).

The TIMESTAMP Format is the following : `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

```
 my $year   = substr($TIMESTAMP, 0, 4);
 my $month  = substr($TIMESTAMP, 5, 2);
 my $day    = substr($TIMESTAMP, 8, 2);
 my $hour   = substr($TIMESTAMP, 11, 2);
 my $minute = substr($TIMESTAMP, 14, 2);
```

**I want to add one day to the TIMESTAMP** and then send it to a function with the following format: `YYYYmmDDHHMMSS`.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Time-Piece-1.21/Piece.pm), Time::Piece was first released with perl v5.9.5.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $date = '2013-07-14 02:33:10';

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%Y-%m-%d %T");
$t += ONE_DAY;

say $t->strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S");
```

Prints
    20130715023310

Answer (score 0):

just put them in as one:

e.g.

```
sub test {
  print ("@_\n");
}

&test("$year$month$day$hour$minute$second");
```

(you didn't talk about the `$second`, but your format needs it)

Comment: Most of all I need to add 24hours (= a day) to this! Unless I would put this `function($year$month$day$minute$second, ...);`

Comment: hmm, forgot about that item - just add `$day +=1;` before the call to the function.

Comment: If $day=31 tomorrow would be the 32! I work with the Gregorian Calendar :p

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider having a look at [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime). You could parse your SQL timestamp using the appropriate [DateTime::Format::…](https://metacpan.org/search?q=DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3a) module. You can add a day uing a method from [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime). You can then format it for output either using an appropriate module from [DateTime::Format::…](https://metacpan.org/search?q=DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3a) or a hand-rolled format using methods from [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime).